# Split functionality in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column empname in a table, the data stored is Lastname,Firstname.

For ex:

```
empname:

Martin,Ricky
Ford,Henry.
```

How to do i via select mysql query get the o/p as:

```
First name  Last name
Ricky       Martin
Henry       Ford
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(empname, ',', -1) AS First_Name, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(empname, ',', 1) AS Last_Name 
  FROM table
```

Though I would prefer to do this on the application doing the output.